# Generic objects along @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration

I'd like to parse generic objects from my configuration yaml file. For example:

```yaml
configuration:
    objects:
        - object1:
             objectName: example
             duration: 360
        - object2:
             differentName: differentExample
             date: 2020.06.06
             isActive: false
```

I tried to implement it by create own configuration class like below but Spring wouldn't able map objects.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configuration")
@Getter
@Setter
class Conf {
    private Map<String, Object> objects;
}
```

There is any way to achieve my goal? It really important to make it generic as much as possible, because there will be a lot of objects with different structures.